# String-based invariant IComparer<string>

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I'm trying to write what is essentially a `StringComparison.InvariantCulture`, but with `StringOptions.StringSort` baked in.
(I need it for `IEnumerable<string>.OrderBy()`, So I can't pass it as a parameter like I can for `String.Compare`.)

However, `StringComparsion.Create` does not take `StringOptions` as an argument.
Is there a one-line way to do this, rather than writing a whole class as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a one-line solution, but it's reasonably simple...

You can create a custom comparer:

```
class InvariantCultureStringSortComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly CompareInfo _compareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return _compareInfo.Compare(x, y, CompareOptions.StringSort);
    }
}
```

And pass it as a parameter to `OrderBy`:

```
var ordered = items.OrderBy(i => i.Name, new InvariantCultureStringSortComparer());
```

Comment: As a total aside, this is one class that I think could be just fine as a Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Little long for a oneliner, but you can avoid creating the class by using the generic `Comparer<>.Create()` to create a comparer that uses a supplied lambda for doing the actual comparison.

```
var comparison = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
var comparer = Comparer<Item>.Create((a, b) => comparison.Compare(a.Name, b.Name, CompareOptions.StringSort));
var ordered = items.OrderBy(i => i, comparer);
```